# Not able to run Python script in Proxy environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy

Hi I am trying to run a python script for downloading data from aws cloud. However I am getting the errors:

File "C:\Users\206504\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 374, in _send
return self.http_session.send(request)
File "C:\Users\206504\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 470, in send
raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://enmovil-logistics.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?prefix=brm_data%2F&encoding-type=url E

I am running the same in-office laptop in a proxy environment. Can you please help to run the code in proxy. The code is working ok in offline or in VPN mode

```
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time


def downloadBRMDataToLocal(file_path):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id='XXXXX',
        aws_secret_access_key='XXXX',
        region_name='ap-south-1',
    )
    s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
    BUCKET = s3_resource.Bucket('XXXX')

    # Get all files from a specific s3 folder
    objs = list(BUCKET.objects.filter(Prefix='brm_data/'))
    objs.sort(key=lambda x: x.last_modified, reverse=False)

    for obj in objs:
        if not obj.key.endswith('/'):
            filename = obj.key.split('/')[1]
            dept = ""
            print(filename)
            body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
            wb = load_workbook(filename=(BytesIO(body)), data_only=True)
            wb.save(file_path)


i = 0
while i < 10:
    # ONCE TRIGGERED, SCRIPT WILL RUN FOREVER (INFINITE LOOP)

    file_path = r"\\mydrive\sharedDataDept\LOG-PP\Rail Stagewise Transit Time Analysis\FY 22-23.xlsx"
    downloadBRMDataToLocal(file_path)
    print("Done")
    freq_mins = 15
    time.sleep(freq_mins * 60)
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Is it `BUCKET.objects.filter()` or perhaps `obj.get()['Body'].read()`? Do you have other boto3 code that successfully communicates with Amazon S3? Does your AWS CLI work successfully (eg `aws s3 ls`)?

Comment: **Side-comment:** It is considered bad practice to store credentials within source code. Instead, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store credentials in a configuration file. You can then remove them from your code.